# Post request transfered to get in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rspec

I have a 2 routes for posts:

```
resources :posts, only: %i[show] do
   collection do
     post 'bulk_delete'
   end
end
```

Somehow in my tests, execution ends up in show route even if I execute bulk_delete request and show request is previously done.

If at some point I do this:

```
post bulk_delete_posts_path, params: { //params}, headers: headers
```

I see in log/test.log it ends up in bulk_delete action and it's fine.

However, if I first execute

```
get post_path(post), headers: headers
```

and after that (anywhere in tests)

```
post bulk_delete_posts_path, params: { //params}, headers: headers
```

the bulk delete requests ends up in show action and I see this in logs:

```
Started GET "/posts/batch_archive" for 127.0.0.1 at 2022-02-01 06:33:46 +0000
Processing by Posts#show as JSON
```

How the heck this could happen? :)

I understand that routes have the same URL structure, but it's explicitly said I want to execute post request and it gets into get

And when I check routes, all looks fine:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/posts/batch_archive', method: 'POST')
{:controller=>"posts", :action=>"batch_archive"}
(byebug) Rails.application.routes.recognize_path('/posts/1', method: 'GET')
{:controller=>"posts", :action=>"show",...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You really need to provide a reproducable example here. I would wager that this is a "methodology error".

Comment: @max example is here, of course adjusted I cannot share all business details. It seems that in specs action_dispatch adds headers["X-Http-Method-Override"] = "GET" (just debugged it), not sure why though